# Cómo AGREGAR una COLUMNA CALCULADA

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, servidor

recién comienzo con SQL Y ASP.NET he usando el patrón de diseño MVC Core y EF, ya he creado las vistas con sus controladores y demás, mi problema esta en que en mi base de datos tengo una tabla Producto que tiene una columna llamada clave de inventario y quisiera que se llenará automáticamente con una concatenación entre la columna nombreProducto y IdProducto ejemplo: "Jabon01", conocen alguna forma de que SQL haga esta procedimiento o función para cada registro que se agregue desde la Web?

Comment: Has visto los triggers, no sería más sencillo que lo generes desde el código?

Comment: @HammerffallBK eso hice amigo, un trigger fue la solución. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existen dos tipos de columnas calculadas, las que se calculan al vuelo, y las que se persisten físicamente almacenando los datos.

```
Create table dbo.producto (idProducto varchar(2), nombreProducto varchar(100))
go
Insert into dbo.producto (idProducto, nombreProducto)
values
('01','Jabon'),
('02','Crema');
go
-- se calcula en cada query
Alter table dbo.Producto
Add claveInventario as concat(nombreProducto,idProducto)
-- 
go
Select * from dbo.producto
```

[image: Calculada]

Este tipo, cada vez que se hace una query se calcula. Ventaja, no ocupa espacio. Desventaja, tiene que computarse "al vuelo".

```
Alter table dbo.Producto
Add claveInventarioPersistida as concat(nombreProducto,idProducto) Persisted
go
select * from dbo.producto
```

[image: Persisted]

La persistida una vez insertados/actualizados los datos, es una columna más de la tabla.

```
Insert into dbo.producto (idProducto, nombreProducto)
values
('03','Champú'),
('04','Colonia');
go
Select * from dbo.producto
```

[image: Resultados]

[Columnas calculadas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Javi, también encontré otra solución mediante un Trigger, después de un insert se actualiza mi campo clave inventario con una concatenación diferente. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server soporta [columnas calculadas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15), que se basan en fórmulas sobre las demás columnas de la tabla, así es justo lo que quieres para lograr la concatenación de las otras dos columnas:

Puedes eliminar la columna actual:

```
alter table Producto drop column ClaveDeInventario;
```

Y luego agregarla nuevamente con una sentencia como esta:

```
alter table Producto add ClaveDeInventario as nombreProducto + cast(IdProducto as varchar(10);
```

Estoy asumiendo que la columna `IdProducto` es de algún tipo de dato numérico y por eso hago la conversión de tipo a varchar. Ajusta el código según tu necesidad.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta jachguate , también encontré otra solución mediante un Trigger, después de un insert se actualiza mi campo clave inventario con una concatenación diferente. Gracias.